# scalability of ROS

Tags: ros, roscore, multimaster

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear Friends,
I was looking for some study on scalability of ROS for multi-robot application. Has anyone conducted any study till date?
I have looked to multi-master package. Any pointers to design documents will also b helpful.

Regards
Prince

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206669/scalability-of-ros/) by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on ROS Answers with karma: 660 on 2015-04-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Re number of connections: AFAIK, all roscpp's IO happens in a select loop (https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/ros_comm-1.8.15/clients/cpp/roscpp/src/libros/io.cpp#L167), so one thread can service many connections.  The select() call, though is O(n) in the number of connections.  There is a Linux specific epoll() which handles large numbers of connections more efficiently.  This page discusses some general networking/scalability issues: http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html.

Re latency: roscpp message latency is ~100us on recent Intel CPUs under Linux PREEMPT_RT.  This is 10-20 times slower than direct kernel sockets and IPC.  Benchmark code: https://github.com/ndantam/ipcbench  Some discussion in our recent article: http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/MRA.2014.2356937.

---

Originally posted by [ntd](https://answers.ros.org/users/1264/ntd/) with karma: 36 on 2015-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on 2015-04-08**:
Is there a design / RFP document from ROS?